# Android TextView weights

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have an issue where I want the left subtext TextView (in grey) to take priority weight in the LinearLayout over the TextView on the right (in yellow). The TextView on the right always seems to take priority, while the one on the left wrapped. Any help is appreciated.

[image: TextView weights issue]

the XML for the layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_nowplaying"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ddd"
        android:textSize="13dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_listeners"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#aaa"
        android:textSize="13dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_bitrate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#aaa"
        android:textSize="13dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not use relative layout ?

Answer (score 2):

Please assign and try weight to all the component of the `LinearLayout`

`layout_width` of all the child should be 0dp in a horizontal `LinearLayout`

Assign `weightSum` parameter to the parent `LinearLayout`